# How can I transmit individual agent number to a variable once the agent pass through any block?

Tags: anylogic

E.g. agent has number value of 3. So, I need the variable gets value of 3 when agent come to an assigned block. Which Java code should I use? Note. The agent's number is defined by parameter and it's generated when a particular agent appears in Source. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On Enter field of the block:

```
variable = agent.parameter;
```